# Can not import spring 3.0.6 jars through Maven in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

**Problem**

I am trying to get a barebones spring mvc project (similar to the template provided in STS) in IntelliJ but the spring 3.0.6 jars do not get imported. Not even after I have done: Right Click on Project Name->Maven->Force Reimport

**What I have tried**

1. Read the following post http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/
2. Added all the spring jar dependencies in my pom.xml
3. Put a properties block outside dependencies with 3.0.6 as the version
4. Added the following repository entries (sorry not sure how to enter xml here):
   http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot
   http://maven.springframework.org/milestone
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
5. Right click on the project->Maven->Force Reimports
6. Nothing comes down.

Anybody know why?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>springplusjasper</groupId>
<artifactId>springplusjasper</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>springplusjasper Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context.support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.web.portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
  <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>springplusjasper</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show a minimal example of the failing POM. (In other words, if you're importing every Spring lib every we don't need to see that--do a small project and show what fails.) Otherwise we're guessing. Also show the exact version you're attempting to use, and the behavior exhibited: compilation errors?

Comment: Its not the POM failing. It's not bringing the spring jars down. I have put the dependencies like this link suggests:http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/ and the spring jars do not get downloaded.

Comment: Yeah, without knowing what's actually in your POM, we have no way of knowing what might or might not be failing.

Comment: How do i paste a pom in here I tried but it seems to take the xml away

Comment: Put it in the question and indent with four spaces. There's formatting assistance available by clicking in the big orange question mark.

Comment: As mrembisz says, your artifact IDs are wrong (and don't match what's in the linked-to article). See why the POM is important now?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really need to add the repositories to your POM file for release versions, as the linked-to article states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifact ids for spring are spring-core, spring-beans etc.

Comment: In this case, that's correct, but the OSGi bundles have different artifact IDs (for example, [spring-core](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.core&version=3.0.6.RELEASE)).

Comment: Thanks that work!! Also thanks for showing me how to add xml to stackoverflow this will make me more agile in my future questions.